# Is there any way to update question's css class based on the response length entered by user in previous field in Survey js?

Tags: surveyjs

Let's suppose we have a textbox which takes user name as an input and based on its character length we want to change the css class applied on next question. How can we achieve it in Survey JS as soon as user types the name in the first textbox?

I have observed onUpdateQuestionCssClasses event is used to change css classes but this event is called before question renders. We want to change css class after the user provides the input in the first textbox.